# Using split on a pandas object giving key error when indexing

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data:

```
    index   Simulation no#  Line    Load    Wind1   Wind2   Wind3   flag    Sequence
0   12  7.0 Line 16 - 19    0.7 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 [('G 05', 'Over-Speed', '1.70')]
1   38  20.0    Line 01 - 02    0.7 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 [('G 01', 'Under-Speed', '5.00')]
2   60  31.0    Line 01 - 39    0.7 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 [('G 02', 'UV', '2.73'), ('G 01', 'Under-Speed...
3   80  41.0    Line 16 - 19    0.7 0.0 0.0 0.2 1.0 [('G 05', 'Over-Speed', '1.72')]
```

The final column is an object type. I wish to extract the final string in these entries, which is actually a time value. So for example, in my first row this entry is:
[('G 05', 'Over-Speed', '1.70')], and I would like to extract the '1.70'. To try to illustrait my issue I have done the following:

```
test = df['Sequence'][0:1]
test

12    [('G 05', 'Over-Speed', '1.70')]
Name: Sequence, dtype: object
```

By splitting on 'Overspeed' I should be able to obtain the strings either side, but when I execute the following I get the subsequent error.

```
test.str.split('Over-Speed')[1]
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-205-8a3c145d0c99> in <module>
----> 1 test.str.split('Over-Speed')[1]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    869         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
    870         try:
--> 871             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    872 
    873             if not is_scalar(result):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4403         k = self._convert_scalar_indexer(k, kind="getitem")
   4404         try:
-> 4405             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
   4406         except KeyError as e1:
   4407             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1
```

Could anyone help me understand what is going wrong here?

Comment: There is no columned named `1`

Comment: `test.str.split('Over-Speed')` returns a Series so further indexing with `[]` tries to slice the Index. Since there is no index labeled with `1` (the only index label is `12`) you get a KeyError. You want the string accessor: `test.str.split('Over-Speed').str[1]` to get the item at the 1 index in the list.

Comment: @ALollz thats great thank you!